# ShadowLayer clipped

Tags: android, android-custom-view, shadow

When I set the [`setShadowLayer(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setShadowLayer) a shadow is generated but is clipped by the view bounds, I had tried everything I found here, in StackOverflow, and nothing have work.

#### I tried:

- `clipToPadding="false` and `clipChildren="false"` (both in the parent viewgroup)
- `setMeasuredDimension(width + shadowElevation*2, heigth + shadowElevation*2)`
- I tried setting the clipBounds with `setClipBounds(...)` (but this only works in >= API 18 and doesn't works)

Comment: Can u try adding some margin to the view for which you are creating the shadow.